# How to add a padding to x axis in canvas js

Tags: canvasjs

In my canvas js chart for each x value I have added a string k. However, last k value of the x-axis is cut off.
How to add a padding-right to each x value? In the following `jsfiddle` also can be noticed that last value is cut off.

http://jsfiddle.net/canvasjs/4hr4xk72/